# Is "It is necessary for them for me to be at the function tomorrow." correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, construction

> It is necessary for them for Jake to be at the function tomorrow.

Is the above sentence correct if I want to say that "for them it is very important for Jake to be present at the function tomorrow"

And by "them" I mean the people who are organising the function. And in the above sentence Jake is a famous person who is going to be the chief guest of that function. So for the people organising the event, it is very important that Jake is going to be at the function.

And could provide some alternative ways to covey the same meaning?

Comment: you must make it clear, _**for whom**_ this is important. For them? For me? for both? Not clear from the context. By "for them" do you mean "in their opinion"?

Comment: By "them" I mean the people who are organising the function. And in the above sentence  'me' refers to a famous person who is going to be the chief guest of that function. So for the people organising the event, it is very important for "me" to be at the function.

Comment: You mean that the people organising the event _**think/believe**_ that this is important for me? You'd better explain this in the body of your question, if you want to receive reasonable answers

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a rule why it's wrong, but the two different uses of "for" right in a row do seem awkward. The meaning you describe is the first meaning I thought of when reading the original, but it wasn't the easiest read. (AmE native speaker)
Have you tried it with fewer "to be" verbs?
Something like

> They find it necessary that I attend the function tomorrow.

or even (if this is also true)

> They said I must attend the function tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can I also write it in this manner: It is important for them that I be at the function tomorrow?

Comment: I'd go with "important to" them, but otherwise seems fine to me. ("use fewer to be verbs" is more advice for effective writing not grammar advice.)

Answer (score 2):

While it's not "wrong", I think it would be much more common to hear "They need Jake to be at the function tomorrow."